# In Cordova, how do I set a different package name for Windows platform?

Tags: cordova, cordova-cli

I know that Cordova now allows for platform-specific package names.  We can do this in config.xml for Android and iOS through the android-packageName and ios-CFBundleIdentifier attributes in the  tag. But, I can't seem to find a similar attribute for Windows 8.1/10 package name.  Does one exist for Windows?  If so, how do I specify it?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you find any solutions?

Comment: Any updates how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [Config.xml documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html) for version 6.0.0 there is attribute `WindowsStoreIdentityName` which takes as value the Store ID generated from Windows Dev Center. e.g. 12345developer.SUPERCOOLAPP

```
<preference name="WindowsStoreIdentityName" value="12345developer.SUPERCOOLAPP"/>
```